# Page scrolling? Maybe z-index?

Tags: css, scroll, z-index, frontend, custom-scrolling

Hey guys I'm sure this question has came up somewhere along the lines, but I'm not really sure the right vocab to use to search for what I'm looking for. So I collect web pages and use them for inspiration for projects and came across  a[website with a scrolling feature](http://focuslabllc.com/)

What I'm looking at is when you scroll down the home page,  goes over top of the header video. I think its sleek but Ive been clicking checkmarks on and off on developer tools to see how they might have done it, I am sure it has something to do with z-index but I'm a little stumped. Maybe because its 1AM.

Sorry for the noob question, I'm just really getting into the front-end stuff.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `div id="content"` has `z-index: 30`. Also, `div id="video-container"` has `position: fixed; top: 0`.

Edit: Note that if you uncheck z-index for #content, it will not change anything (at least not for me in Chrome) so that might be redundant unless they have other things going on with other pages that use it. But if you change #video-container so it has a higher z-index, then it will be on top of the other content.